# How to re-partition to add a new partition after installing with one partition?

Tags: partitioning

I just installed everything in one partition. How can I create an additional NTFS partition on this disk? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image: Gparted window showing 927.61GiB /dev/sda partition plus 3.9 GiB swap in extended partition]

Comment: u can see i have one etx4 partition, i want one nfts partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)